# React Native: NSATSGlyphStorage inconsistency on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm having those warnings on the xcode log after fetching data from remote JSON:

```
2016-01-27 11:31:20.407 App[556:543614] NSATSGlyphStorage inconsistency. Cannot find run storage for character range {24 1} for CTRun 0x17d1d3d0. Ignoring the run...
2016-01-27 11:31:20.426 App[556:543614] NSATSGlyphStorage inconsistency. Cannot find run storage for character range {22 1} for CTRun 0x17feb2d0. Ignoring the run...
2016-01-27 11:31:20.426 App[556:543614] NSATSGlyphStorage inconsistency. Cannot find run storage for character range {43 1} for CTRun 0x17feb2f0. Ignoring the run...
2016-01-27 11:31:20.440 App[556:543614] NSATSGlyphStorage inconsistency. Cannot find run storage for character range {42 1} for CTRun 0x190604f0. Ignoring the run...
2016-01-27 11:31:20.448 App[556:543614] NSATSGlyphStorage inconsistency. Cannot find run storage for character range {22 1} for CTRun 0x17ff48d0. Ignoring the run...
2016-01-27 11:31:20.457 App[556:543614] NSATSGlyphStorage inconsistency. Cannot find run storage for character range {23 1} for CTRun 0x17fbcd40. Ignoring the run...
2016-01-27 11:31:20.458 App[556:543614] NSATSGlyphStorage inconsistency. Cannot find run storage for character range {48 1} for CTRun 0x19060c90. Ignoring the run...
```

What could it be?